# Kendo UI UTC date issue

Tags: date, datepicker, kendo-ui, utc

I have a strange issue where the edit template for our grid is causing issues when editing dates.

The dates are stored on the server in UTC timezone. I use the following pattern to set the timezone:-

```cs
private DateTime _minDate;
public DateTime MinDate
{
    get { return _minDate; }
    set { _minDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
}
```

The dates get loaded into the grid using WebApi OData services.

```cs
{
    "Id":50088,
    "ProductId":101437,
    "Valor":"12224000",
    "ISIN":"CH0122240002",
    "Description":"Outperformance Bonus Certificate, Multi Shares",
    "Provider":"CSIB",
    "AlertedTicker":"KO UN",
    "ProtectionPercentage":1.0,
    "ProtectionType":"Protection Lost",
    "UnderlyingCurrency":"USD",
    "BarrierLevel":190.0,
    "BarrierPercentage":70.0,
    "BarrierType":"Low",
    "BarrierId":0,
    "EventStructureId":170378,
    "Date":"2013-11-20T00:00:00Z",
    "Comment":null,
    "Confirm":false,
    "Reject":false
}
```

The OData service correctly serializes the UTC date and the date get to the UI intact.

After editing the date using a date picker control but just typing using the keyboard the data is sent back to the server in the wrong format.

```cs
{
    "odata.metadata":"http://local.host:51850/web/odata/$metadata#PendingBarrierAlerts/@Element",
    "Id":50088,
    "ProductId":101437,
    "Valor":"12224000",
    "ISIN":"CH0122240002",
    "Description":"Outperformance Bonus Certificate, Multi Shares",
    "Provider":"CSIB",
    "AlertedTicker":"KO UN",
    "ProtectionPercentage":1.0,
    "ProtectionType":"Protection Lost",
    "UnderlyingCurrency":"USD",
    "BarrierLevel":190.0,
    "BarrierPercentage":70.0,
    "BarrierType":"Low",
    "BarrierId":0,
    "EventStructureId":170378,
    "Date":"2013-11-20T23:00:00Z",
    "Comment":null,
    "Confirm":false,
    "Reject":false
}
```

Notice the date has a changed time !

How can I edit UTC dates in a grid and correctly return them to the server using OData as a transport and a remote datasource ?

Answer (score 1):

Dates are always created on the client side as local Dates (not as UTC dates). To intercept and avoid what happens in result you need to use the requestEnd event to transform those dates before the Grid/DataSource start working with them.

You can see similar approach covered [here](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What I use to do for avoiding what @PeturSubev says is implementing a `parse` function in my `DataSource.model` that correctly initializes dates.

```
dataSource:{
    ...
    schema:{
        parse:function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (idx, elem) {
                if (elem.Date && typeof elem.Date === "string") {
                    elem.Date = kendo.parseDate(elem.Date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
                }
            });
            return response;
        }
    }
```

}

So I let KendoUI work with whatever dates they want.