# Keep date in UTC in Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to fix a bug that we are experiencing when using Kendo UI. The backend sends dates in UTC, which is how we would like them to be displayed in the UI. However, as far as i understand the UI always converts the datetime to the timezone of the local browser. Now i have tried the approach detailed here: https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides which i arrived to from here: [Kendo UI UTC date issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909793/kendo-ui-utc-date-issue) but it does not work. I am also working with a `Kendo Grid` which complicates this a little bit. I have also

The code that i adapted is below:

When defining the grid:

```
.Columns(columns => {columns.Bound(c => c.Birthday)
          .Format("{0: dd/MM/yyyy}")
          .Width(dateColumnWidth).MinResizableWidth(dateColumnWidth)
          .Title("Birthday")
          .Groupable(false);
```

When defining some source params:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
           .Ajax()
           .Read(read => read.Action("ReadUsers", "Birthday").Data("AddFilters"))                                       
           .Events(e=>e.Error("onError").RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
```

Then the onRequestEnd function:

```
function onRequestEnd(e) {
        if (e.response.Data && e.response.Data.length) {
            var persons = e.response.Data;
            for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {            
             persons[i].Bithday = new Date(persons[i].Bithday).toISOString();
             //console.log(persons[i].Bithday)             <-- this outputs correct value to the console
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the issue still persists. I added some console.log() to debug this and it seems like the date is actually converted correctly, just that my field is never updated with it.

[image]

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm having the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

So you like the UI to display in UTC format? Have you tried changing `.Format("{0: dd/MM/yyyy}")` to UTC format, `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"`?

Your console log worked because you changed it to an ISO string, `toISOString()`.

Comment: yes tried doing that but when changing the locale in the browser, the date and time change and dont stay in UTC